# Subview not properly adjusting location on orientation change

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, subview, orientation-changes

So I decided to add a subview to my parent view, I created a new view and controller, and at runtime I initialize the subview's viewcontroller using initwithnibname to instantiate the view with the nib file.  Then I simply make the call to addsubview and the view appears as expected and the subviewcontroller is properly handling all events in that subview... and stuff in the parent view continue to go to the parentview controller.

So, all is well and right with the world....

That is until I change orientation, when I change orientation, the subview does properly rotate itself in terms of its facing landscape or portrait, but it does not change its absolute location in the parent view... it continues to appear at the absolute coordinates it had for the other orientation, and does not adjust as one would expect.

I tried adding the various orientation change events to the subviewcontroller willanimate.. didrotate... but they never get called as the events only seem to go to the parentviewcontroller and do not get passed into subviewcontrollers.

This subview is using constraints, so the nice little autoadjust bars in IB are not there to try to solve this... so how the heck to I set this up so that when the orientation changes, the subviews actual location in the parent view should/must change as well?

Comment: put the code you add your subviews and set frame. give a image of wrong position after rotate.

Comment: can you provide us a screenshot of what's happening or code that you've done so we can help

Comment: There is really no code to show, as the even handlers never get to the subview, since they only get passed to the rootview... so that code never executes.  As to a screen shot, I can, but its pretty simple to explain.

Lets say I have a subview that is at location 100x100 in landscape mode and the screen dimensions in this mode are  500 x 1000 for example... When the screen is rotated into portrait mode, where the screen dimensions are now 1000x500 the subview remains at 100x100 it is not adjusting its location based on the layout change.